# Elasticsearch Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [scroll]

Tags: php, elasticsearch, php-7.2, elasticsearch-6

I am trying to use the PHP API, and same example as given in the code

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_search_operations.html#_scrolling

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$params = [
    "scroll" => "30s",          // how long between scroll requests. should be small!
    "size" => 50,               // how many results *per shard* you want back
    "index" => "my_index",
    "body" => [
        "query" => [
            "match_all" => new \stdClass()
        ]
    ]
];

// Execute the search
// The response will contain the first batch of documents
// and a scroll_id
$response = $client->search($params);
```

But getting error like this Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [scroll].

Currently using Elasticsearch version 6.2.2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you put scroll parameter in json body, but it should be instead in the URL. e.g

```
index-name/_search?scroll=30s
```

Don't forget to remove it from `$params` as well

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentaly put scroll attribute inside body.

Comment: Please add some code (avoiding scroll attribute) so other users can test what you're describing. Thanks!